# Angular 5 form group errors with __zone_symbol__state: true

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, angular-forms, angular-validation

On submitting Angular form, there is no error in the individual form controls. Still the form state is `INVALID`. with the following error object.

> ```
> errors : {
>     __zone_symbol__state: true, 
>     __zone_symbol__value: null
> }
> ```

Here is the form group with custom validator

```
this.form = fb.group({
        start_date: [new Date(), [ Validators.required ]],
        start_time: ['13:00'],
        end_date: [new Date(), [ Validators.required ]],
        end_time: ['16:00'],
    }, {
        validator: EndDateValidators.checkStartDate
    });
```

This `EndDateValidators.checkDtartDate` is validating the startDateTime is before endDateTime.

It is validating correctly and one error getting this object.

> ```
> errors : {
>     __zone_symbol__state:true
>     __zone_symbol__value: {
>         minDate:true
>     }
> }
> ```

**Not sure why it is giving an error under `__zone_symbol__value`**

If I remove the custom validator everything works fine. But then I need to validate startDateTime-endDateTime on submit inside component.(I think that is little dirty.)

I think may be the problem is with Custom Validator code:

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';
import {reject} from 'q';
export class EndDateValidators {
    static checkStartDate(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
            // Not showing exact calculation to make this code short.
            const diff = endDateTime - startDateTime;
            if (diff <= 0)
                resolve({minDate: true});

            resolve(null);

        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the Promise used in the custom validator, that is used when we make a server call for the validation.

In this case, I am really not making any calls to the server so making Custom Validator simple like below fixed my problem.

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';
export class EndDateValidators {
    static checkStartDate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        let ret: ValidationErrors = null;

        // Not showing exact calculation to make this code short.
        const diff = endDateTime - startDateTime;
        if (diff <= 0)
            ret = { minDate: true };

        return ret;

    }
}
```

This solves the problem.

But not sure yet, if I need to make server call for the validation, I would get the same problem!?

Answer (score 4):

How's your validator being used?

If youre using an async validator, you must pass an empty array for the second FormControl parameters so it should be something like this:

```
myField: ["", [], [myAsyncValidator]],
```

If you change this to

```
myField: ["", myAsyncValidator]
```

You'll get the  **__zone_symbol__state** error

Answer (score 1):

Use ***asyncValidator*** instead of ***validator*** as follows:

```
this.form = fb.group({
        start_date: [new Date(), [ Validators.required ]],
        start_time: ['13:00'],
        end_date: [new Date(), [ Validators.required ]],
        end_time: ['16:00'],
    }, {
        asyncValidator: EndDateValidators.checkStartDate
    });
```